Is it possible to use mv-expand inside iif clause in KQL?
I have a column called Data which sometimes contains a single object and sometimes contains array of objects, e.g.
{
  "field1": "data"
  "field2": "data"
}
... or
[
  {
    "field1": "data"
    "field2": "data"
  },
  {
    "field1": "data"
    "field2": "data"
  }
]

I would like to use mv-expand only on the lines which contain an array in the Data column. Is this possible? I tried this query:
| extend DataLength = array_length(Data)
| extend Data = iif(DataLength == 1, mv-expand Data, Data)

But it fails with
Syntax error: Missing expression: If the keyword 'mv-expand' is intended to be part of an expression it needs to be bracketted as ['mv-expand'].",
Which I'm unable to fix. I tried
| extend DataLength = array_length(Data)
| extend Data = iif(DataLength == 1, ['mv-expand'] Data, Data)

But that is just "Request is invalid and cannot be executed.",

If I understand your question correctly would something like this work?  mv-expand should work ok with a variety of data types even if it's a single length array.
let T = datatable(Key:int, Data:dynamic) [
1, dynamic(['data1']),
2, dynamic(['data1', 'data2']),
3, dynamic(['data1', 'data2', 'data3']),
4, 'data1'
];
T
//| where array_length(Data) > 1 //Comment line in or out for only Data colums with more than one entry
| mv-expand Data to typeof(string)




Key
Data




1
data1


2
data1


2
data2


3
data1


3
data2


3
data3


4
data1




I would like to have it handle both cases at the same time, here is an example:
let T = datatable(Key:int, Data:dynamic) [
1, dynamic([{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value"}, {"field1": "value1", "field2": "value"}]),
2, dynamic({"field1": "value1", "field2": "value"}),
3, dynamic(['data1', 'data2', 'data3']),
4, 'data1'
];
T
| mv-expand Data to typeof(string)

the second row isn't handled correctly
Key Data
1 {"field1":"value1","field2":"value"}
1 {"field1":"value1","field2":"value"}
2 {"field1":"value1"}
2 {"field2":"value"}
3 data1
3 data2
3 data3
4 data1

Thanks Ville that is helpful context.  What output are you specifically wanting to see?
